# MSCOMCTL Treeview OCX replacement for OpenEdge 64 bits

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

We started to test OE12.4 to migrate our systems from 11.7, but 12.4 licenses doesn't include 32-bit versions of PROWIN32 and AppBuilder anymore. Therefore, we're unable to update and develop new applications using MSCOMCTL Treeview OCX, as we did until now. This isn't a problem for future programs, but for migration it is. We're unable to run programs from PROWIN (x64) which uses MSCOMCTL Treeview OCX's, as well as all other programs who uses 32-bit DLL's. The programs compile like a charm, flawless, but doesn't execute.

I tried to register MSCOMCTL OCX throug CMD in c:\windows\system32 directory but, as expected, it didn't worked. For this DLL, as a discontinued resource, Microsoft doesn't provide a 64-bit compiled code.

I'm aware that exist a open project called PureAblTreeView, which works pretty good and doesn't rely on DLL's dependency, but this object was built on ADM2 and the majority of my old programs are ADM1. Therefore, I'm unable to use that solution without rewrite my programs, which can't be done at this time. I even tried to "rebuid" PureAblTreeView as a SmartV8Object, but it didn't worked. Too many differences to be solved and too little time to achieve a running solution.

Is there any workaround for this situation, besides rebuild the programs?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Hi! Have you found a way to run the OCXs in version 12? I'm looking for ways to do, but haven't found anything yet

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading Knowledge Base article [000153835](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-compile-and-run-an-OpenEdge-application-with-32-bit-OCX-using-OpenEdge-12) correctly, then your issue should have been addressed in 12.4:

> The 12.2.5 update and the 12.4 release have re-introduced the
> AppBuilder to 32-bit OpenEdge.  It is now available to run from the
> installed Program Group icons.

Comment: If it was reinstated, should solve my problem, but it wasn't. Progress isn't issuing OE Studio 32-bit licenses. Instead, they included AppBuilder in 4GL Development license. To use it, I need to downgrade my OE Studio 64-bit license to 4GL Development 32-bit license, completely giving up 64-bit development OE Studio license, as it can't be "re-upgraded" to OE Studio. Also, according to Progress itself, this reintroduction is a palliative solution, which may be completely removed sometime in future. Unfortunatelly, that isn't a viable solution.

Comment: So it's a licensing issue? In that case it's a cost exercise.

Comment: No, man... It isn't a licensing issue. 32-bit AppBuilder was discontinued by Progress and reinstated for some clients because they had problems with 32-bit OCX and DLL's, but they don't have plans to continue supporting AppBuilder in 32-bit releases. In fact, 32-bit apps are condemned to extintion, as happened with 16-bit apps some time ago. I'm looking for a way to use 32-bit OCX in 64-bit apps or an affordable way to convert those OCX into 64-bit ones.